# How to load base64 string in webview?

Tags: android, pdf

I am trying to read pdf file using "iText" library & I am getting page using "**getPageContent(int number)**"

This method is  returning byte[] and when byte[] is loaded into WebView it is displaying an empty view .

```
try {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(getAssets().open("policy.pdf"));
            int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            String base64 = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(
                    reader.getPageContent(1), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
            WebView webView = new WebView(this);

            webView.loadData(base64, "text/html", "base64");

            setContentView(webView);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to print the Base64 encoded string into Webview?. You want  it in readable format  or in an encoded format?. Are you sure?

Comment: I want to display that pdf page as image in webview

Comment: where's the image in the code?. You can use PDFReader to get the content as String or byte[] .  So the content of that page is an image?.

Comment: it displaying unreadable data

Comment: What's the content of the PDF page?. Image in complete or textual matter?.

Comment: pdf have only text........................................

Comment: no result yar it displaying lot of text like "Tm[0.00(nd)14.0TM<fah>-jhgsu]......................................"

Answer (score 1):

You want Text from the page to be displayed on the Webview. The whole  method you are using is incorrect as far as i can see in the iText API.

Here's the corrected code ( untested as i don't have the library license )

```
try {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(getAssets().open("policy.pdf"));
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();


    PRTokeniser tokenizer = new PRTokeniser(reader.getPageContent(1));
    String content="";
    while (tokenizer.nextToken()) {
        if (tokenizer.getTokenType() == PRTokeniser.TokenType.STRING) {
            content = content +"\r\n<br />" + tokenizer.getStringValue();
        }
    }

    WebView webView = new WebView(this);

    webView.loadData(content, "text/html", "UTF-8");

    setContentView(webView);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @BhaskarReddy I've edited the code. Try that now. Sorry for a silly mistake .

Comment: no result yar  it displaying lot of text like "Tm[0.00(nd)14.0TM<fah>-jhgsu]......................................"

Comment: @BhaskarReddy are you new to the iText API?. I don't think that you are calling the methods correctly. Here's the code  i've tried to make up from your requirement.  Check it now.

Comment: Ya now I am getting text but it is totally different from original , it displaying word by word and headings not appearing

Comment: I observed, displayed data not from visible content , it displaying hidden text...

Comment: @BhaskarReddy That my friend is an issue which is unrelated to the question . 

You can get the continuous text by removing `"\r\n<br />"` .
I haven't used iText till now. So i don't have any means to test any code.


Try reading the api more >  [Refer](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=275)

Comment: If this way not possible, please tel me how to convert pdf to html page

Comment: @BhaskarReddy  I really can't help with the pdf to html page . You are asking an entirely  new set of code. You do some code and ask another question, i will attempt at it.  But i don't understand why  u 'unaccepted' the answer , which is correct for this question. You were going in a different path clueless and i guided you. Is this some fun thing?. Unaccepting after accepting?.